# second value in select is displayed as selected. It is wrong

Tags: reactjs, typescript

By default, the second value in the selection is displayed as selected. This is not correct - because the second in is the first element from the renderCityOptions list.
It is also worth noting that cities are a constant that is simply exported from the configuration file, while store.initialFaceState.city is dynamically assigned first, it is taken from sessionStorage and assigned to store.initialFaceState.city. This behavior only occurs after a page refresh. In all other cases (navigation, selection change) the select works fine.

```
const renderSelectedCityOption = () => {
  const selectedCity = store.initialFaceState.city;
  console.info(selectedCity);
  if (selectedCity) return (
    <option key={selectedCity} value={selectedCity}>
      {selectedCity}
    </option>
  );
  return null;
};

const renderCityOptions = async (): Promise<JSX.Element[]> => {
  const filteredCities = Object.keys(sities).filter(elem => store.initialFaceState.city !== elem);

  return filteredCities.map((elem, i) =>(
    <option key={i} value={elem}>
      {elem}
    </option>
  ));
};

const handleCityChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
  return store.setFaceState(
    e.target.value,
    store.initialFaceState.product,
    store.initialFaceState.wgt
  );
};

return (
  <>
    <main className='shop'>
      <div className='overTop'>
        <h2>Face</h2>
        <div className='lay_out'>
          <p>
            <span>Choose city</span>
            <select
              id='city'
              name='city'
              onChange={handleCityChange}
            >
              { renderSelectedCityOption()}
              { renderCityOptions()}
            </select>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </>
);
```

the result looks like this-

```
city1 that in store.initialFaceState.city
city2 is displayed as selected
city3
```

as a result, the wrong option is displayed as selected in the select. It must match.
Expectation:

```
city1 that in store.initialFaceState.city displayed as selected
city2 
city3
```

I believe that this problem is related to the fact that renderCityOptions is rendered before renderSelectedCityOption after the page refresh. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Thanks all.